# redirect standard output from a batch (stdout) to a text file before reboot

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to redirect standard output from a batch script (stdout) to a text file.

Command used:

```
ECHO "This is test" > test.txt
ECHO "Hello World 1" >> test.txt
ECHO "Hello World 2" >> test.txt
....
ECHO "Hello World 10" >> test.txt
```

In case of a system reboots in between these commands, I loose the contents redirected to "stdout" and file `test.txt` is not found on system resume.

Can anybody tell a solution to retrieve the information redirected to stdout and dump to a text file at this instance?

For example if system restarts at `ECHO "Hello World 5" >> test.txt`, I want `test.txt` to look like:

```
This is test
Hello World 1
Hello World 2
Hello World 3
Hello World 4
```

Comment: `>` writes a file to the disk. `>>` appends to a file on the disk. I see no reason, why that file should disappear at reboot (unless it is in a raid- or disk-cache without a battery, but even then a "reboot" (including proper shutdown) would write the cache to disk)

Comment: Try running the batch file itself with >> test.txt 2>&1 options... Even with reboot, it will always echo the outputs and errors to the test.txt file rather than adding redirection to each and every echo

Comment: Specify output file with full path to a directory all users have permissions to write. Otherwise the current working directory on execution of the batch file could be a directory which is by default write-protected and this is the reason why `test.txt` is not created in directory `X`. Do not expect that working directory on execution of a batch file is the directory of the batch file.

Comment: Thanks for the help. @Mofi the output file gets created when everythinng runs fine. Poper output is generated in that case. But when reboot occurs in between, i do not find the test.txt at the specified directory.

Comment: @thiruvenkadam, looks like >> test.txt 2>&1 options will work. I will test it once again and will confirm. Thanks for the help